# Memory leak issue with NVD3

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory, nvd3.js

We are using NVD3 js chart where we are seeing memory leak issue. In our application we are auto reloading our page (not browser) every 2 minutes. When there is a reload we are doing ajax call and returning a jsp file which renders NVD3 chart in the page. Whenever reload happens, the javascript memory (task manager of Google chrome) is getting increased gradually and at some point (ie., say after 12 hrs) memory size is so high the browser get crashed. We tried by making the div null/empty whenever reload happens, we tried clearing the svg element also, but that also doesn’t solve the issue. Much Appreciated if any help on this.

Comment: Have you tried using the Memory tab in the devtools to investigate what is taking up the most memory over a long period of time? Often these problems are not straightforward to debug and can be different per case. In some cases, this can be caused by having too many callback functions loaded in the memory in which their contexts hold references to huge objects.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, sorry for late reply. We don't have many callback functions. We identified that there is one chart, among 8, because of which memory leak is happening. When we commend out that particular chart, everything works fine and no memory leakage observed.

Comment: Glad you found the root cause!

Comment: Hi @Derek朕會功夫. We found the issue, but couldn't be able to fix it :(

Comment: If the leak is coming from a library that you don't control, then the best you could do is to file a bug or find a new charting library unless your team fix it yourselves locally which I would not recommend.

Comment: Hi @Derek朕會功夫! Yes, it looks like library has the issue. I have suggested team to get new charting library now. Thank you for being around to help on this issue.

Comment: Hey mate, if you share a sample, someone can solve your issue or find a workaround and this will help more people. Or maybe you can even open issue on the library's GitHub and the bug gets fixed.

Comment: codtex, Derek,
Looks like we have found the issue. nvd3 charts have window.resize() method which is causing the memory heap issue. We commented it out and everything is working fine. I understand that whenever our browser window is resized we won't be able to fit our charts automatically into it. Will check if this bug has already been addressed in newer version.